# Clickable icon on image

Tags: android

I want to add a clickable “favorite icon ❤️“ on the top of the ImageView for an Android project. I found similar to this in Zillow application as in the attached image. Any help please?

[image from Zillow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YtpnM.jpg)

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: What you've achieved so far? 
If you've not achieved anything then try to do some research and then implement it and then post your query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use checkbox for this, use 2 icon one is favorite (full heart) and the other is an unfavourite icon(heart with the only border) and set In the selector

set selector file in android:button property in the check box

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatCheckBox
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:button="@drawable/selector_checkbox"/>
```

Here is the selector file,

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/checkbox_favorite" />

    <item
        android:state_checked="false"
        android:drawable="@drawable/checkbox_unfavourite" />
</selector>
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow this code ,

```
 <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="center"// your scale image on your need!
        android:src="your_image" />
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_favorite_24"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:clickable="true"// doesnt need just hard code like setOnClick...
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```